# Why is mongoose changing variable

Tags: javascript, mongoose

It seems like mongoose (5.6.11) is changing my value in a query. Is this normal? Is there a way to keep the string case the same?

```
console.log('>>',req.body.visitor)
Visitor.findOne({ email: req.body.visitor.email }).then((visitor)=>{
....
```

server console/log:

```
>> {
  email: 'Maida_VonRueden@hotmail.com',//this is a fake email generated with faker
  enteredValidationCode: '969621'
}
Mongoose: visitors.findOne({ email: 'maida_vonrueden@hotmail.com' }, { projection: {} })
//                                   ^ Why does the email change here?
```

Do I have to use regex to query case insensitive (`Visitor.findOne({email: {$regex: new RegExp(req.body.visitor.email, 'i')}})`)?

Comment: What does your mongoose schema look like?

Comment: @AKX well that seems to be the issue, completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AKX comment my schema required lowercase

```
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true, // < HERE
    required: [true, 'cant be blank'],
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'],
    index: true
}
```

Per [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options)

> boolean, whether to always call .toLowerCase() on the value